# Reduce SAT to SAT with at most one satisfying assignment in polynomial time

Tags: algorithms

Is it possible to turn, in polynomial time, a SAT instance into a SAT instance that is unsatisfiable if the original was unsatisfiable and that has exactly one satisfying assignment if the original was satisfiable?

Comment: This is a well-known open problem. The best known result is the Valiant–Vazirani construction, which gives a randomized reduction that succeeds with a small but non-negligible (inverse polynomial) probability.